# Calculate shared room cost

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The case is that I rent a 4-shared dorm. For the first week I stayed alone and covered the full rental fee. The next week I received a roommate and we agreed to share the rental fee (fee divided by 2) from his move in date. A week later we received another roommate and we all agreed that the cost will be equally shared since his move in date.
Is there any way in Excel to calculate payable amount for each person at the end of the month.

Comment: Maybe divide the rent by the number of days it covers giving you a daily rent and then calculate from there?

Answer (score 1):

As per @Darren Bartrup-Cook's comment, this is more of a calculation than an excel problem per se. My way of doing it would be;

1)Find number of days each person has lived in

2) Put them in a ratio of you:roomate1:roommate2

3) divvy out the rent on the ratio of how many days each person has spent. Not actually the same as your prescribed method, but I think it's fairer to pay the same amount per day?

Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8mSYCXxSrWPW3M8WAFfAzhF32xq9JZWU6swLlWUXJ4/edit?usp=sharing